# java keystore tool

Tags: security

If i connect to a remote server that uses SSL my browser would request its digital certificate from the server and the server would get it from its key-store am i correct ?

Is java key-store tool being used to perform the same action ?

Comment: The server will get its key from *some* kind of keystore, but not necessarily the Java one (depending on what the server application is).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Java keytool.exe utility is used to maintain digital certificates and their associated keys in a key-store file.  It can also be used to generate key-pairs, signing requests and for other security-data oriented functions.